# Есть ли в c++ map на основе сортированного массива?

Tags: c++

Есть ли в c++ map на основе сортированного массива? Если да, как он называется

Answer (score 2):

В C++ нет. Но есть в boost: [boost::container::flat_map](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/doc/html/container/non_standard_containers.html#container.non_standard_containers.flat_xxx)

Answer (score 0):

В бусте есть [flatmap](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/doc/html/boost/container/flat_map.html).

В стандартной библиотеке такого нет. Но написать свою обертку обычно не сложное дело.

[std::lower_bound](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) позволит написать как оператор `[]`, так и вставку.